# How to excute AsyncTask inside onLocationChanged() method in Android

Tags: android, gps, android-asynctask

I have class that extends `AsyncTask` class and  I  create instance of this class of this `AsyncTask` class uses data comes from GPS driver from the method

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
```

from interface `LocationListener`.

I want to know why why the application to execute `AsyncTask` instance inside the method  `onLocationChanged()` ?! As I want to execute something in background only when the location is changed

Comment: Could you, please, be more specific? You have overriden onLocationChanged(), then you are starting AsyncTask from your overriden onLocationChanged(), then what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        new yourAsyncTaksk(location).execute();

}
```

make a constructor for your asyncTask , with Location object as argument.

Comment: Could you please share the complete code for background task in onLocationChanged method alone?